# Inject a view into a view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to inject a view into another view to avoid code duplication.

I came up with the idea of this:

```
struct WrapperView: View {
    
    var injectedView: some View
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            injectedView
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error: `Property declares an opaque return type, but has no initializer expression from which to infer an underlying type`

How can I achieve something like this in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use generics. Here, the type `Content` conforms to `View`, so we can pass in something like `Text`.

Something like:

```
struct WrapperView<Content: View>: View {
    let injectedView: Content
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            injectedView
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
WrapperView(injectedView: Text("Hello"))
```

---

If you want to call it similar to when creating the `VStack` like this:

```
WrapperView {
    Text("Hello")
}
```

You can change `WrapperView` to this:

```
struct WrapperView<Content: View>: View {
    private let injectedView: () -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder injectedView: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.injectedView = injectedView
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(content: injectedView)
    }
}
```

We use `@ViewBuilder` so we can build view content in the closure, allow us to do the following:

```
WrapperView {
    Text("Hello")
    
    Text("world!")
}
```

Comment: Amazing, that's it. Thank you!

Comment: @NicoS. You can also make it so you call it like `WrapperView { Text("Hello") }`, which I can add as an example if you would like.

Comment: Sure go ahead. Future me will appreciate it :P

Comment: @NicoS. Added it :)